# Force.com IDE: ApexClass and ApexTrigger no more supported?

Tags: force.com, force.com-ide

Since today my Force.com IDE project on a spring 18 sandbox doesn't sync my Apex classes modifications anymore. When I try to edit the project components I have the message:

```
The following components type(s) are not supported, so no component will be     added to the package manifest editor for these types:
* ApexClass
* GlobalValueSet
* AuthProvider
* ApexTrigger
See log for detailed messages.
```

Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, the Author Apex permission was unchecked for my profile :s
Hope it helps.